# add Jekyll Ideal Image Slider Plugin to my site

Tags: plugins, jekyll

I try to add Jekyll Ideal Image Slider Plugin to my site.(https://github.com/jekylltools/jekyll-ideal-image-slider#integration-suggestions)
Here is the cade in my Gemfile

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
  #add jekyll feeds
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
  # gem "chronic"
  # gem "google-api-client"
  # gem "jekyll-ga"
  # amp jekyll facility
  gem "amp-jekyll", "1.0.2"
  gem "jekyll-email-protect", "1.0.3"
  # translation
  gem "jekyll-i18n_tags", "~>1"
  gem "ideal-image-slider"
  gem "jekyll-maps"
  gem "jekyll-sitemap"
end
```

But when I run  `bundle install`
it gives me the error

```
Could not find gem 'ideal-image-slider' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

I tried to run the following `gem install "ideal-image-slider"`
but it gives me the error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'ideal-image-slider' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I have a Bundler version 1.16.1. Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing gem can't be installed because it is a jekyll plugin that needs to be included directly into your plugins directory. You don't need to specify it in the Gemfile.

> Installation
>
> Add _plugins/ideal_image_slider.rb to your _plugins folder.
>
> Add this line to your _config.yml file: iis_slider_array: []

Comment: Hi Marcanuy and many thanks for your answer, I did what you said and I don't know yet if it is working because I have another error. I had to do it with all plugins. I think there is something that is wrong  because the documentation for plugin jekyll-i18n_tags for example says that I can do it with gem (https://github.com/KrzysiekJ/jekyll-i18n_tags) and I have the same error. Anyway, I will accept your answer when I will be sure that it works putting "plugin_name.rb" in _plugins folder. Do you guess what could be the issue ?

Comment: What error gives after removing the ideal-image-slider gem from Gemfile?

Comment: the error is described on this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052293/cannot-build-the-site-on-the-preview-server

Comment: Finally, I think that "ideal-image-slider" has not been gemified. So I added "ideal_image_slider.rb" to my _plugins directory. My question is closed. Thank you for your answers