# Cannot Build the site on the preview server

Tags: jekyll

I am a beginner on jekyll. I am following the documentation advice to Build the site on the preview server.
Here is what a did : 
- install the last version of ruby
$ruby -v -> ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
$ gem --version -> 2.6.14
- Install Jekyll
$gem install jekyll bundler -> Version of jekyll : jekyll-3.6.2

When I try to build the site on the preview server (bundle exec jekyll serve) there is the following error :

jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  (/Users/admin/Documents/Perso/Site-Internet/Jekyll/inger/_config.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 16 column 1

the line 16 is the first line uncommented that shoul be processed. It is this one

```
title: Inger Hair at Home at Aix en Provence (line 16)
```

I don't see what can be wrong. Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Post your _config.yml content

Comment: https://github.com/flamant/fileshare/blob/master/_config.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaml files are sensitive to spaces, in your `_config.yml` you have:

```
# Exclude from processing.
# The following items will not be processed, by default. Create a custom list
# to override the default setting.
 exclude:
   - Gemfile
   - Gemfile.lock
   - node_modules
   - vendor/bundle/
   - vendor/cache/
   - vendor/gems/
   - vendor/ruby/
   - Inger-Analytics-feb0aa8b73d1.json
   - .gitignore
```

When it should be:

```
# Exclude from processing.
# The following items will not be processed, by default. Create a custom list
# to override the default setting.
exclude:
   - Gemfile
   - Gemfile.lock
   - node_modules
   - vendor/bundle/
   - vendor/cache/
   - vendor/gems/
   - vendor/ruby/
   - Inger-Analytics-feb0aa8b73d1.json
   - .gitignore
```

Note the space before `exclude:`. Then it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It seems that it works now. But I am not sure at 100% as I have another issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063381/jekyll-issue-with-amp-filter-rb)